# RESTEASY002020: Unhandled asynchronous exception with quarkus 1.0 Final and RestEeasy JAX-RS Resource

Tags: resteasy, quarkus

I have this code, that performs parallel execution of some function that does http calls, this located inside some @Singleton service that is called from the RestEeasy JAX-RS Resource

```
final Flowable<Map<String, List<Data>>> relatedMaps = Flowable.range(0, requestList.size())
 concatMapEager(index ->
    fetchByHttp(requestList.get(index))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                  .toFlowable(),
                        requestList.size(),
                        1
 );
```

where the fetchByHttp is:

```
 Singe fetchByHttp(request) {
 return Single.fromCallable( () -> {
    ...restClient.getData(request)
    ...
```

requestList.size() is about 100. or less.

and **sometimes** I get this issue:

```
14:28:35 ERROR [or.jb.re.re.i18n] (RxCachedThreadScheduler-232) RESTEASY002020: Unhandled asynchronous exception, sending back 500: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:91)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsyncResponseConsumer.sendBuiltResponse(AsyncResponseConsumer.java:148)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsyncResponseConsumer.internalResume(AsyncResponseConsumer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsyncResponseConsumer$CompletionStageResponseConsumer.accept(AsyncResponseConsumer.java:237)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsyncResponseConsumer$CompletionStageResponseConsumer.accept(AsyncResponseConsumer.java:216)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:62)
    at io.smallrye.context.propagators.rxjava2.ContextPropagatorOnSingleCreateAction$ContextCapturerSingle.lambda$onSuccess$2(ContextPropagatorOnSingleCreateAction.java:50)
    at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeThreadContext.lambda$withContext$0(SmallRyeThreadContext.java:215)
    at io.smallrye.context.propagators.rxjava2.ContextPropagatorOnSingleCreateAction$ContextCapturerSingle.onSuccess(ContextPropagatorOnSingleCreateAction.java:50)
    at io.smallrye.context.propagators.rxjava2.ContextPropagatorOnSingleCreateAction$ContextCapturerSingle.lambda$onSuccess$2(ContextPropagatorOnSingleCreateAction.java:50)
    at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeThreadContext.lambda$withContext$0(SmallRyeThreadContext.java:215)
```

On Resource side:

```
    @Timeout(20000)
    @GET
    @Path("/data")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public CompletionStage<Data> getData(){

        final Single<Data> dataSingle = service.getData();

        final CompletableFuture<Data> dataFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        dataSingle
                //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(dataFuture::complete);

        return dataFuture;
    }
```

Found [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3578). If it is fixed. Then **Q**: what's going on and how handle it?

Quarkus 1.0 Final.

Comment: I was about to say that it looks like a bug and ask you to open an issue, but I see you already commented on the issue. Thanks

Comment: hmm. ok: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6006

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257978/quarkus-resteasy-ws-rs-resource-completionstage-exception-handling - if I don't use CompletionStage then seems it is stable. But I have to block thread on the Resource.